# HTML Page Keeps Scrolling to Top of Page when Checkbox is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to write a script that will scroll to a random element with a checkbox after that element's respective checkbox is clicked on. However, my current issue is that the page keeps scrolling to the top whenever a checkbox is clicked. I have also tested this manually and the same issue occurs whenever I click on any checkbox.

```
RandomGameSelector.html
```

```
<style>
    ul.no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

   ul > li.video-game {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

   ul > img {
      width: 110px;
      height: 130px;
}

   #video-game label {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<body>

<div>
   <div>
      <h2>Microsoft Xbox</h2>
         <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/call of duty 3.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Call of Duty 3</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode I</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/shrek.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Shrek</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/soulcaliber ii.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>SoulCalibur II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/spiderman 2.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Spider-Man 2</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/star wars episode iii.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div>
      <h2>Microsoft Xbox 360</h2>
         <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/assassins creed ii.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Assassin's Creed II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/assassins creed brotherhood.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/bully scholarship edition.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Bully: Scholarship Edition</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/dead rising 2 off the record.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Dead Rising 2: Off The Record</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/homefront.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Homefront</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/madden nfl 11.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Madden NFL 11</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/rage anarchy edition.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Rage [Anarchy Edition]</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/ufc undisputed 2010.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>UFC Undisputed 2010</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
       
   <div>
      <h2>Nintendo Entertainment System</h2>
         <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/mickey mousecapade.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Mickey Mousecapade</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/super mario bros duckhunt.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Super Mario Bros. / Duck Hunt (Focus on Mario Bros, Try to Establish a Score for Duck Hunt)</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/teenage mutant ninja turtles.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/tetris.png">
            <li id="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Tetris</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   const games = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)");
   const checkbox = Math.floor(Math.random() * games.length);
   games[checkbox].click();

   function scrollToGame() {
      const box = document.getElementById("video-game");
      box.scrollIntoView({
         behavior: "smooth"
      });
   };
</script>

</body>
```

I've been trying to find solutions to this problem for hours now, but I have not had any success with any of the suggestions provided in the different forums and threads I've searched. One of the most common solutions that I saw to potentially solve this issue is to use the following CSS property:

```
   #video-game label {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, this has not been working on my end. I've also read about setting the display to none, but that hides the checkboxes whereas I want them to be present in my case.

Comment: IDs are required to be unique, you shouldn't have duplicate `id="video-game"`.

Comment: Use `class="video-game"` instead. Then have `scrollToGame()` select a random element from `document.querySelectorAll(".video-game")` and scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are reusing the same id multiple times  which are supposed to be unique.

> ID attribute values should be unique. HTML with two or more identical ids does not validate, and will produce unpredictable results.

I removed all but one `id="video-games"`, so you should see it scroll to the single element with the ID now.

```js
const games = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)");
   const checkbox = Math.floor(Math.random() * games.length);
   games[checkbox].click();

   function scrollToGame() {
      const box = document.getElementById("video-game");
      box.scrollIntoView({
         behavior: "smooth"
      });
   };
```

```css
ul.no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

   ul > li.video-game {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

   ul > img {
      width: 110px;
      height: 130px;
}

   .video-game label {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <h2>Microsoft Xbox</h2>
         <ul id="games-1" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/call of duty 3.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Call of Duty 3</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode I</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/shrek.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Shrek</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/soulcaliber ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>SoulCalibur II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/spiderman 2.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Spider-Man 2</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/star wars episode iii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div>
      <h2>Microsoft Xbox 360</h2>
         <ul id="games-2" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/assassins creed ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Assassin's Creed II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/assassins creed brotherhood.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/bully scholarship edition.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Bully: Scholarship Edition</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/dead rising 2 off the record.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Dead Rising 2: Off The Record</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/homefront.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Homefront</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/madden nfl 11.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Madden NFL 11</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/rage anarchy edition.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Rage [Anarchy Edition]</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox 360/ufc undisputed 2010.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>UFC Undisputed 2010</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
       
   <div>
      <h2>Nintendo Entertainment System</h2>
         <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/mickey mousecapade.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Mickey Mousecapade</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/super mario bros duckhunt.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Super Mario Bros. / Duck Hunt (Focus on Mario Bros, Try to Establish a Score for Duck Hunt)</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/teenage mutant ninja turtles.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Nintendo/Nintendo NES/tetris.png">
            <li id="video-game" class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="scrollToGame()"/></label>Tetris</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```